# Dll safe exception handling

Tags: c++, exception, dll

I'm pondering on using exception handling in some libraries I'm writing.
The code base may ultimately be implemented in a number of dlls.
I know that using exception handling across dlls is a bad idea - however, would it be safe to do the following?

```
class IDllSafeException
{
public:
    virtual void AddRef() = 0;
    virtual void Release() = 0;
    virtual int GetErrorCode() const = 0;
    virtual const char * What() const = 0;
};
```

Assuming this is a valid approach, I'd really like to catch by value, rather than pointer.  That way I could have a wrapper class which automatically calls Release().

Thus...

```
template <typename T>
class SafeExceptionT
{
public:
    SafeExceptionT(T *);            
    SafeExceptionT(SafeExceptionT &);
    SafeExceptionT & operator=(SafeExceptionT &);
    ~SafeExceptionT();

    int GetErrorCode() const;
    const char * What() const;
private:
    T * m_pException;
};

typedef SafeExceptionT<IDllSafeException> SafeException;
```

Being a template means all catch blocks would generate their own layout and call can m_pException->Release() in the destructor (using AddRef() when copying occurs).  Also I could implement different types of exceptions as needed.

My catch block would then look like this...

```
try
{
    ThrowSomething();
}
catch(SafeException except)
{       
    const char * psz = except.What();
    int nErrorCode = except.GetErrorCode();
}
```

...

```
void ThrowSomething()
{   
    // Concrete implementation omitted for brevity
    throw new DllSafeException(1, "something went wrong");
}
```

I would have thought that would work but my exception handler does not get caught, even though I've a non-explicit constructor for SafeException.

However I can only seem to catch via pointer...

```
try
{
    ThrowSomething();
}
catch(SafeException except)
{       
    /// IGNORED!
    ...
}
catch(IDllSafeException * pExcept)
{       
    // CAUGHT BY POINTER but we now have to micro-manage.
    const char * psz = pExcept->What();
    int nErrorCode = pExcept->GetErrorCode();
    pExcept->Release();
}
```

Are there special rules for how types are matched in exception handlers?

Comment: Using exception handling across dlls is not a bad idea at all. It just requires very careful handling, just like C++ exceptions in general. If exception to be thrown is defined in this dll then you need to import rtti for this class from this dll. If it is defined somewhere else then you need to import rtti for exception class from there. Also you should throw by value and capture by const reference. If you still want to throw a pointer then make virtual destructor instead of COM-style `Release` and reinventing smart pointers.

Comment: You CANNOT throw exceptions, particularly class-based exceptions, over the DLL boundary unless both the DLL and the caller are built against the same Runtime Library, share the same RTTI, the same Memory Manager, etc.  Just don't do it, it is NOT SAFE.

Comment: Thanks for the comments though there seems to be disagreement.

I would have thought that the memory management concerns are resolved if using a virtual method and throwing via pointer.
Also, any ideas why the exception is not being caught by value as  SafeException?

I may just go back to using return codes if this is going to be a problem.

Comment: If it is not getting caught than most likely you didn't import exception class from dll. Also conditions listed above ("both the DLL and the caller are built against the same Runtime Library, share the same RTTI, the same Memory Manager") are actually conditions for safe use of C++ code imported from dlls in general, not just for exceptions.

Comment: If I made the destructor virtual, wouldn't this cause heap deallocation in the wrong dll?  That's why I went with ref counting.  Though, happy to be corrected if I'm wrong.

Comment: Its not getting caught but its all in the same binary at the moment.

Comment: `ThrowSomething` method doesn't throw `SafeException`

Comment: `throw new` always throws a pointer and cannot ever be caught by value. There is absolutely no requirement to use `new` in a throw statement.

Comment: SafeException has a non explicit constructor.  I was hoping to catch the thrown pointer in it.  The point of throwing via pointer is so that I can use virtual methods (Release) to destroy the object without worrying about memory manager.

Comment: You can just throw by value without worrying about memory management.

Comment: I can't throw by value across the dll boundary without extra legwork.  Which I'm trying to avoid using an abstract base class.

Comment: Why not? Throw by value, capture by const reference. Just a typical scenario. Even if you use abstract base exception class it would be a good idea to derive it from `::std::exception`.

Comment: Though wouldn't different dlls potentially be linked against differing stl implementations cause a problem?

Comment: If dlls are linked against differing runtime libraries then you'll get big problems anyway. Such situation must be avoided.

Comment: This is the whole reason behind throwing an abstract base class.... all methods are virtual.  When Release is called, it invokes delete/~tor in the context of the binary it came from.
I understand the general concept of throwing by value/catching by reference but I'm trying to see if there's a way of getting round the lack of an ABI standard in C++ by using abstract methods for the dll boundary - in the same way that COM does.
I know that one thing that most compilers agree on is vtable layout - thats why COM can pass the IUnkown pointers around.

Comment: Catching by reference will perform proper cleanup. Using abstract methods for the dll boundary does not help getting around lack of ABI standard at all. And COM does this by enforcing essentially plain C ABI, not just by using virtual methods that just happen to form a particular vtable layout.

Comment: COM does this by ensuring that all vtables are built in a particular order.
Any methods that are invoked on a virtual instance will defer to the vtable.
The vtable will have been constructed in the implementing binary and will hence call the memory manager from where the object was created.
I'm not sure I understand where you are coming from.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040205-00/?p=40733

Comment: Even though you have `IDllSafeException` with COM-like virtual methods it will not give you the same level of compatibility as COM have.

Comment: Agreed.  But that not the point - I dont need tan implementation of  QueryInterface.  I just need a consistent vtable across, compiler/memory manager agnostic.  Release will always be the same place in the vtable.  Hence the correct implementation will be called.

Comment: The thing is that declaring some class with virtual methods does not give you consistent vtable layout. In case of COM it is actually the other way around: you get consistent vtable layout because it is required by COM. Not only that, but COM also governs calling convention (stdcall), exception handling (no exceptions) and other things.

Comment: To my knowledge, declaring a class WILL give a consistent vtable layout.  Otherwise ATL wouldn't work.  C++ vtables are fundamental to COM (for ATL and MFC at least).
With regards to the calling convention, that's a good point but the calling convention just has to be agreed upon.  A borland compiler might use a different default.  Though I wasn't intending to use anything other than MS compilers but adding explicit stdcall would give compiler compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested, the above code does successfully circumvent the dll boundary exception issue by using abstract base classes and relying on consistent vtable layout across compilers.

I tested this on VS2008 and VS2017.  I had a dll built in each environment and a console app in each.  The dll raised exceptions and the exception class internally aggregates an object to ensure heap allocation would take place.

I also mixed and matched versions of the C-runtime (static vs dll) between different dlls/console apps.  I could successfully raise/catch my exception across the dll divide.

As expected, the vtable layout ensures that the delete/~tor happens in the correct binary.

The only caveat is that you must throw by abstract interface.  Which also means ensuring you manually call pEx->Release.  This is not pretty I know but I still don't know why my other class does not capture the exception via it's non-explicit constructor.

[VS2008 Example Debug Session](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBomf.png)